# pass data from excel to word with macro runtime error 13

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

Hi I'm trying to create a macro that transfer data from excel to word, originally was made in Excel 2007 but now I'm working in Excel 2013 and it gives me a mismatch runtime error 13 and can't figure out how to solve it.

I checked the references but it seems the problem isn't there.

```
Sub toWord()
    wArch = Hoja1.Range("C3").Text & Hoja1.Range("C2").Text & ".dotx"

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True

    objWord.Documents.Add Template:=patharch, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0

    For i = 1 To Hoja1.Range("c1").Value

        datos = Hoja1.Range("B" & i).Text
        reemp = Hoja1.Range("A" & i).Text

        With objWord.Selection.Find
            .Text = datos
            .Replacement.Text = reemp
            .Execute Replace:=2
        End With

    Next i

    objWord.Activate
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What line is producing the error? I assume you don't have your variable declared right and it is happening where you are setting those. datos = Hoja1.Range("B" & i).Text

Comment: Change Hoja1.Range("B" & i).Text to Hoja1.Range("B" & i).Value

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that Run Time Error 13 because there is an error in the template file path `patharch`

`objWord.Documents.Add Template:=patharch, NewTemplate:=False, DocumentType:=0`

Please ensure that the template file path and name is correct.

See this

[image]

Comment: Thank you Siddharth Rout!! we ended changing the whole code. Googling a lot! we found one that was working (we were running out of time to deliver the macro) I wil post the solution the next week for others to see. Thank you for taking your time to help me.